# Unable to Create folder in SharePoint from Rest API from Postman

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to hit `/_api/Web/folders` API from Postman with body:

```
{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Folder"},"ServerRelativeUrl":"Test Document Library/Opportunity 5"}
```

And getting response like:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "The property '__metadata' does not exist on type 'SP.Folder'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type."
        }
    }
}
```

Please help with this.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `Content-Type` header value to "`application/json;odata=verbose`" should solve the problem.

However, the call you are using won't create the folder properly. When you add a folder in SharePoint using the Web UI it actually adds two things: the folder and a list item. It's the list item that shows up in the List View. Also, there are two names.

The name of the list item and the name of the folder. You set the name of the list item by setting the Title field value and you set the name of the folder by setting the `FileLeafRef` field value. When you add a folder using the REST API, it just adds the folder.

If you want to add the folder properly you need to use the legacy REST API (ListData.svc) or you need to make two calls using the current REST API.

I cover this topic and more in [SharePoint REST API and Lists with Folders](https://www.paitgroup.com/blog/sharepoint-rest-api-and-lists-with-folders)

Comment: thank you, i'll try this and reach-out to you

Comment: Hi i tried like this as well but unable to create folder . Is there any way to create folder from postman.
from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest
link i was looking solution but getting above response.
can you please help me to create folder from Postman.

Comment: yes odata=verbose does solves the metadata issue but it gives access denied now.